# How can i only get column which addScalar from DTO class?

Tags: java, hibernate, projection

I have a question about addScalar in Hibernate. Example I have DTO class:

```
public class FieldInfoDTO {
    private String fieldInfo1;
    private String fieldInfo2;
    private String fieldInfo3;
    private String fieldInfo4;
    private String fieldInfo5;
}
```

Then in DAO class I did this:

```
String sql = "SELECT field_info1 AS fieldInfo1 FROM tbl_field_info;"
SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sbQuery.toString());
query.addScalar("fieldInfo1", StringType.INSTANCE);
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FieldInfoDTO.class));
return query.list();
```

I expect the result will be like this in Postman:

```
{
   "fieldInfo1" : "value"
}
```

But it return:

```
{
    "fieldInfo1" : "value",
    "fieldInfo2" : null,
    "fieldInfo3" : null,
    "fieldInfo4" : null,
    "fieldInfo5" : null
}
```

Is there any way to display only the column I addScalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is due to the statement :

```
query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(FieldInfoDTO.class));
```

as it formats the result as per the attributes in  `FieldInfoDTO` class(though the other fields gets set to `null`)

Try removing it and fetch the result in list of `String`.

Comment: You mean the only way to get fieldInfo1 is remove the other fields? Is there any way to keep all of them and only display fieldInfo1?

Comment: You can definitely do so, I answered as per your question only. What and how to display is in your hands, you can Iterate the list and then fetch only fieldInfo1..

Comment: Thank you for answering! I will try to do that.